# Message now reads: No signal coming from computer

Tags: windows-7, bios, hardware-failure, cabling

When I power on, my monitor reads: No signal coming from computer. Then the monitor enters Power save mode. The computer is non-responsive and it also beeps every 5 seconds.

Comment: when is this coming? When you switch on/reboot? What're the specifications? Did you do any changes to hardware/software? Without these info there's no way to answer these. [edit] the info in and flag for reopening

Comment: Or go edit your [initial question](http://superuser.com/questions/471123/my-computer-starts-and-then-enters-save-mode-and-beeps-every-5-seconds-hdmi-does) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to bad RAM. If you have more than one, then remove them all other than one and try to turn it on. If this fails, swap the stick one at a time until it turns on without the beeping.

I would also suggest you take out the battery on the board, leave it out for 2 minutes, then replace it and try again.

I would also look through these [beep codes](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm). I can't copy the content to SuperUser as I don't know what BIOS you have.

Comment: I apologize if I've offended anyone for not asking a question according to the rules. Also, Dave Rook, that was an excellent idea. It was a memory bar, but it still seems to crash after I sign in and then restarts. Got any more ideas?

Comment: In that case, please mark this as the answer and ask a fresh question as the issue has changed quite a lot.

Comment: How do I mark this as the answer?

Comment: Beside my answer should be an empty tick - just click on it and that is it :)